# passing Intent from class which extends ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

This is my class which is population items in a list view , things goins well , onItemClick method is executed when clicked on a listitem , but when i pass an intent from there , it is not passing the intent , plz help me out.

```
public class VideosListView extends ListView implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private List<Video> videos;
private VideoClickListener videoClickListener;
MainActivity ma;
private Context mcontext;

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VideosListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mcontext=context;
}

public void setVideos(List<Video> videos){
    this.videos = videos;
    VideosAdapter adapter = new VideosAdapter(getContext(), videos);
    setAdapter(adapter);
    // When the videos are set we also set an item click listener to the list
    // this will callback to our custom list whenever an item it pressed
    // it will tell us what position in the list is pressed
    setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

// Calling this method sets a listener to the list
// Whatever class is passed in will be notified when the list is pressed
// (The class that is passed in just has to 'implement VideoClickListener'
// meaning is has the methods available we want to call)
public void setOnVideoClickListener(VideoClickListener l) {
    videoClickListener = l;

}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) 
{
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// When we receive a notification that a list item was pressed
// we check to see if a video listener has been set
// if it has we can then tell the listener 'hey a video has just been clicked' also passing the video
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,AnVideoView.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
    mcontext.startActivity(intent); 

    Log.i("VideoListView", "I am Clicked");
    if(videoClickListener != null)
    {
        videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(videos.get(position));
        Log.d("My Position ","position is" + position);
    }
```

this is my classsnow from onItemClick() i want to pass to a activity class , how to do that thanx helping

Comment: is onItemClick() working fine?

Comment: Yah its working good , i have printed something in log file , and it is printing accurately

Answer (score 0):

Try This...
It will help you.

```
Activity activity;

    public VideosListView(Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        this.activity=activity;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity,AnVideoView.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
        activity.startActivity(intent); 

        Log.i("VideoListView", "I am Clicked");
        if(videoClickListener != null)
        {
            videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(videos.get(position));
            Log.d("My Position ","position is" + position);
        }
```

Comment: @pranav If any question is helpful to you, then mark that question as accepted.. Its important in the aspect of the answering people. Because on that basis you are going to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

in onItemClick((AdapterView adapter, View v, int position, long id)
i have created a contructor to the class extending BaseAdapter , and then from the there we can easily pass our intent... it is working for me , anyways thaks helping me a lot guys

we can pass the position in the contructor , and do whatever we want to do with the item selected.